# How to implement back button functionality in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am developing a Sencha Touch application. I have 2 pages in my application. I have a button in my first page. When I click on the button, it goes to the second page by the following code:

```
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('Appname.view.ViewName'));
```

Now when I deploy my application on device, and press device back button, it directly comes out of the application. It does not return to the first screen

I know there is navigation view for this, but I dont want to use it. I want that when the user presses device back button, then the user should be returned to the first page. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define routes in your Controllers. See the [Ext documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-routes). So switching back to the previous view will be possible.

Here is an Example for you:

```
Ext.define('XXX.controller.Home', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            // ...
        },
        routes: {
            'home': 'showHomeView'
        }
    },

    // ...

    showHomeView: function () {

    }
}
```